# In a masless spring, all locations in the spring feel the same forces? What about the masses attached to it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces, spring

For example in this scenario :

[image]

Lets say the system is in rest, so the top of the spring feels downwards force of $(m2+m3)g$ and upwards force of $k\Delta x$, does it mean that the bottom of the spring and therefore the mass attached to it M1 feels the same thing ?

I need the force diagram of this system, I'm not sure how to do it.

My guess would be the only thing the same for the masses is the force of $k\Delta x$ but then it would contradict my belief that M1 feels some kind of downward force from this spring ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's like this.

[image: diagram]

Don't rely on what you guess. Rely on your math. What it tells you is the correct thing.

Spring doesn't feel anything! It's mass-less.

To analyze systems with Newton's third law, is the best way.

Read first chapter of David Morin's Classical Mechanics for deeper understanding of the concept. Somewhere it talks about the four common forces in mechanics. That may help.

---

P.N.

That's $N_{G,1}$ in the diagram for the mass 1, if can't read it.

---

In response to your comment,

A compressed spring pushes outward. A stretched one pulls inward. 
Determining if a spring is stretched or compressed can be handled in this way:

Set coordinates to both top and the bottom of the spring.

Subtract the coordinates to find the instantaneous length of the spring.

Comparison of "current length" and the "rest length" tells you it is compressed or stretched.

Comment: Thanks, My issue was mainly figuring out to which direction $k\Delta x$ goes in the mass $M1$,and I'm still not sure about it, can you elaborate on how you know $k\Delta x$ works downwards in mass M1 ?
I thought maybe because the springs want to strech upwards then it will cause an upwards $k\Delta x$ force on M1.

Comment: @user3575645 The spring wants to get back to its equilibrium length. So it wants to somehow repel both M1 and M2.

Comment: Thanks! for somereason I got confused I thought it would want to strech only to the direction that compressed him

Answer (score 0):

A good intuitive way of checking your action and reaction diagrams is to imagine that you remove one element (say M1) and put your hand there with the objective that the red point doesn't move. How much force would you feel? (to phrase it otherwise, how much weight do you bear?)

Same question if you remove the ground rather than M1 and hold the whole system.

Btw, it is not explicit from your question, but you must be aware that $\Delta x$ here is only allowed to take one value at equilibrium.

Comment: Thanks thats a good method, it does help me reassure there is an upwards force from the spring on the top masses, but If I remove the floor I will have to compenstate for the N force because of mg, but it doesn't help as much to figure out the direction  $k\Delta x$